# Checkbox Alignment

Tags: jquery, css

I'm wanting to figure out why the th checkbox never gets aligned with the rest of the column. All checkboxes should be center aligned.

http://jsfiddle.net/waZRR/

UPDATE: Actual Live Version

[My link](http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/bios/quotes)

Comment: Did you know that you can check styles of page elements using DOM inspector in Chrome or Firebug in FF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You your dribble example it worked by putting

```
 table tr td:first-child { text-align: center !important; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waZRR/4/

**Update**

Vega's solution is clearly better! Just ignore me^^

**Update 2**

Use the css as Vaga' suggested, and add new padding rules. like this:

```
 .table thead th:first-child,
 .table tbody td:first-child { text-align: center; padding:4px 0px; }
```

Then it looks good :)

Comment: It was still a good suggestion. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Updated with a new awncer.
The checkbox in the <th> propperbly needs speacial attention, just play around with padding until it's centered

Answer (score 2):

Add this style rule,

```
.table thead th:first-child,
.table tbody td:first-child { text-align: center; }
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/waZRR/3/

Your live version was different from what you had in fiddle. But the problem was on the below style in `myccs.css`,

```
table .checkbox {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 8px 13px;
}
```

Try adding a style like below,

```
table .checkbox {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 8px 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: This answer is great but for some reason when I try and put it into the live version its still not aligning. Let me try and include all files so you can see the exact live version.

Comment: @user1406861 Check my updated post.. there are other way you can fix this too..  Perhaps you should look at why you needed that much padding. The reason why I say this.. above is overriding some rule which was defined before.. but it is better to set it right in the beginning so you don't have to patch later.

Comment: yeah for some reason I can't tell if that did anything.

Answer (score 1):

The padding on your table head is greater than the on your cells. You will need to modify the padding on it to align your `th` checkboxes with the rest of your `td` like so:

```
.table thead th {
  padding:7px;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/waZRR/1/